# Nestjs Mongodb create collection dynamically

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I have try to create new collection for every device registration. I have tried to create by below code but it's not working

```
mongoose.model('devices'+name, DeviceSchema)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below line above the code, it will work

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MongoDB, {dbName: 'devices'});
```